# Move to the previous occurence or cancel previous replacement when using vim replace mode?

Tags: vim

When I use

```
%s/foo/bar/gic
```

to replace *some* of the **foo** in the context with **bar**, the only available choice is **(y/n/a/q/l/^E/^Y)**

specifically:

y -- yes

n -- no

a -- all

q -- quit

l -- make current change and stop

^E-- scroll one line down

^Y-- scroll one line up.

what if I want to move the cursor to the previous occurence, or undo the last replacement?

it seems the only way to get around is to 1. quit replace mode by **q** 2. undo previous change by **u**, 3. enter replace mode from current line by **,.$s/foo/bar/gic**.

by the way, emacs does this function nicely.

Comment: The whole point of `/c` is to prompt for confirmation. If you don't want to perform your substitution on the current match... don't press `y`. Alternatively, you can use `:grep` or `:vimgrep` and use the quickfix list to navigate the matches and perform your substitution when needed with `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [vim-easyreplace](https://github.com/sosmo/vim-easyreplace) which I wrote because I wasn't happy with Vim's `:s//c` option. It lets you replace highlighted matches of your last substitution in normal mode by pressing ctrl-n so you can move around and edit freely at the same time.

Alternatively Vim's built-in `cgn` replaces the next match in front of your cursor with the text you type and is repeatable with `.`, but it doesn't let you to use regex stuff like back references.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple workflow:

```
gg            " jump to first line of the buffer
/foo          " jump to first occurrence of 'foo'
nnn           " jump to next interesting occurrence of 'foo'
:s//bar/ig    " perform your substitution
nn            " jump to second next occurrence
&             " repeat the substitution
n             " jump to next occurrence
and so on...
```

And a variant using `:vimgrep` and the quickfix list:

```
:vim foo %       " search for 'foo' in the current buffer

jump to next/previous matching line with :cn/:cp

:s/foo/bar/ig    " perform your substitution

jump to next/previous matching line with :cn/:cp

&                " repeat your substitution

jump to next/previous matching line with :cn/:cp

&                " repeat your substitution

and so on…
```

Comment: doesn't work if the line has multiple matches though

Comment: @sosmo: I'd be *very* surprised.

Comment: It replaces every occurrence on a line at once which is something you probably wouldn't want if you're trying to use it like 'c'